# Add my Youtube playlist on my website

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

I add videos to my site via the JavaScript YouTube API. It works well except that at the end of the video playback, there are several video choices that appear on my screen. I want to choose the video or videos that appear at the end of my video.

How can I do this?

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. I'm not familiar enough with the YouTube API to give a proper answer, but I don't believe such a thing is possible. As far as I'm aware, YouTube itself selects which videos appear at the end of yours unless you're partnered with them, in which case you'd get to choose which videos appear the end.

Comment: It is possible. I think but i'm sure that it is possible to replace all the video with an image.